# Python - Flag row without using loop

Tags: python

I would like to know if there's any function that I can use for flag (when there's pop up date. for ex:row 188,189,190...etc.) without using loop. please see attached excel file.
Thank you so much!
[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HEM5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with using pandas...

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'path\to\file'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
flags = ~df['pop up'].isna()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan. Unfortunately I don’t have pandas.